# Making multiple microservices in single project in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, code-analysis, sonarqube-scan, spring-boot-maven-plugin, sonarscanner

[Sonar showing multiple projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMJbj.png)
[Folder structure of microservices in system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKKKC.png)

Hi Everyone!

Recently I started learning microservices architecture. I developed it with spring boot maven but when it comes to deploying on sonarqube it showing 6 projects instead of one.

I want there should be only one project with src folders of my 6 microservices. I have seen somewhere on sonar already implemented.

I tried to put diffrent sonar.projectKey for but same project name for every micro-service but didn't get the desired output in sonar

I tried to make them into single project but it's showing multiple projects in sonarqube